# Consistent char to int

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am working on implementing the RNN model for which I need to convert all my characters into integers based on the dictionary as follows.

```
charset={'!',
 '#',
 '(',
 ')',
 '+',
 '-',
 '/',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '=',
 'B',
 'C',
 'E',
 'F',
 'H',
 'I',
 'N',
 'O',
 'P',
 'S',
 '[',
 '\\',
 ']',
 'l',
 'r'}
```

I use the following method to convert `charset` into integers based on a dictionary as follows.

```
char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(charset))
```

Which gives me the following output.

> {'2': 0,  'F': 1,  '-': 2,  'O': 3,  '1': 4,  'E': 5,  '4': 6,  '!':
>   7,  'H': 8,  'S': 9,  '/': 10,  '\': 11,  '#': 12,  'l': 13,  '=':
>   14,  'P': 15,  'C': 16,  '+': 17,  'r': 18,  'B': 19,  '(': 20,  ')':
>   21,  ']': 22,  '3': 23,  '[': 24,  'I': 25,  'N': 26}

Now I close my Jupyternotebook and load the data again and run the above two lines of code again. This time the mapping is different as follows.

> {']': 0,  '\': 1,  '(': 2,  '=': 3,  '!': 4,  'F': 5,  '3': 6,  'S':
>   7,  '4': 8,  'N': 9,  '+': 10,  'l': 11,  'H': 12,  'E': 13,  'C': 14,
>   'I': 15,  '-': 16,  'B': 17,  ')': 18,  'P': 19,  '[': 20,  'r': 21, 
>   '1': 22,  '/': 23,  '2': 24,  '#': 25,  'O': 26}

How can I get consistent `char_to_int` every time I run it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` objects in Python do not have order. If you make `charset` a *list* instead of a *set*, then your result will be consistent between runs.